# detect reading a non-digit using scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

Hey everyone thanks for the advise. unfortunately i'm not allowed to use such functions. so i wrote this code, which works great with 1 problem. if i enter lets say 'hhjk' it will freak out. i want to clear the buffer after the first 'h' is detected as non-digit.. heard about the function fflush but i can't get to understand it..

```
int get_int() 
{
    char inp; /*inp, for input*/
    int number; /*the same input but as integer*/
    int flag=0; /*indicates if i need to ask for new input*/

    do  {
        flag=0; /*indicates if i need to ask for new input*/


        scanf("%c",&inp);

        if (inp<48 || inp>57 ) /*this means it is not a number*/
        {
            inp=getchar(); /*Here i clear the buffer, the stdin for new input*/
            printf("Try again...\n");
            flag=1;
        }
        else
          if (inp>53 && inp<58 && flag!=1) /*this means it is a number but not in the 0-5 range*/
          {
              inp=getchar(); /*here i clear the buffer, the stdin so i can get a new input*/
              flag=1;
          }

        } while (flag);

    number=inp-48; /*takes the ascii value of char and make it an integer*/ 
    return number;
}
```

Comment: `reading a non-digit` Well what do you want to cover? All and any possible incorrect input? Or just make sure the user doesn't enter single chars?

Comment: if he enters the digit '8' i need to print "wrong" and if he enters lets say 'j' i need to ignore and wait for new input

Answer (score 4):

A simple way is to input a string, then check to make sure everything in there is a character. We can use `strtol()` to check since it [returns a 0 when it can't do the converstion](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/), the only condition is since you want 0 to be valid input, we have to put a special condition on the check:

```
int main()
{
    char input[50];  // We'll input as a character to get anything the user types
    long int i = 0;
    do{
        scanf("%s", input);  // Get input as a string
        i = strtol(input, NULL, 10);  // Convert to int
        if (i == 0 && input[0] != '0') { // if it's 0 either it was a numberic 0 or
            printf("Non-numeric\n");     // it was not a number
            i = -1;   // stop from breaking out of while()
        }
        else if(i<0 || i > 5)
            printf("wrong\n");
    }while (i < 0 || i >5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the seldom seen %[] format for the scanf family.  In the code below, I have %[0-9].  This gives us only numbers.  ( haven't shown the return code, etc.)

```
do {
        if ((scanf("%[0-9]%c", input, &nl) == 2) && (nl == '\n')) {
                value = strtol(input, NULL, 0);
        } else {
                value = -1;
        }
} while ((0 <= value) && (value <= 5));
```